# How can I set the background colour in a webpage so that it will be printed by default?

Tags: html, css, printing, background-color

By default some web browsers (e.g. Firefox and IE) have the background colour disabled in the print dialogue box.  Is there html/css that I could use to create background colour for an element that would be printed even in this case?

Alternatively is there a neat way to warn the user before they print the webpage?

Edit: I didn't make it clear before, but the webpage is designed to be printed.  The main background is white, but occasional words and phrases are highlighted with a background colour.  To make matters slightly more complicated, the page content and highlighting is largely determined by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For warning the user, you might use the `onbeforeprint` event attribute.

Answer (score 1):

In theory you could style a single pixel image to be absolutely positioned behind the content and scaled … but that's a horrible approach to the problem.

Using up large chunks of toner or ink can be expensive. Create a print stylesheet optimised for a white background instead.

Comment: This is probably the best answer.  Long story short, no there's no CSS /JS way to print background images.  Allowing Javascript (CSS isn't really a programming language) that kind of access to a computer is a bad idea (security speaking).  Browsers will print something in an "IMG" tag.  You could layer an IMG tag behind some content but that's a terrible approach.  Optimise the color for white on a printer stylesheet is a good recommendation.

Answer (score -1):

I think its better to convert your background color to a small image  and repeat it in your background using  css.

```
background: url("../images/headerblue.gif") repeat-x scroll left 7px transparent;
```

Comment: That's a terrible idea. It will use up more bandwidth, take more work and will not solve the problem since browsers that don't print background colours won't print background images either.

Comment: I'm using the background colour for highlighting words/phrases.  The page background is white as it's intended for printing.

Comment: @tttppp — Use bold or italic instead.

Answer (score -1):

Use a different media type for print:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

Comment: That won't override the "Don't print backgrounds" user preference.

Comment: that's a browser preference, you can only do so much until the user overrides.

Comment: there are very limited options in the print dialogue of browsers, looking at them right now I don't see any option for not printing background colors. if this is happening it's probably your printer setting, not your browser setting...

Comment: and who is downvoting all the answers?? that's not what the downvote is for people...

Comment: — For example: http://www.steve.maurer.net/tutorials/software_tutorials/background_print_id.htm

Comment: The only answers that have been downvoted (at the time I write this comment) are ones that simply won't work. Answers that "simply won't work" are not useful. The downvote arrow has the tooltip "This answer is not useful". It is exactly what downvoting is for.

Comment: @Quentin Have you ever taken a look at IE recently? there is no such option.

Comment: — I'll worry about that if I ever want to print a webpage with its background colours intact from IE. The question, however, is explicitly about browsers which do have that option.

Comment: @Quentin and what browsers would that be? there are none that I know of recently with that option. I think you should also read the faq about downvoting before going click crazy... ["The upvote privilege comes first because that's what you should focus on: pushing great content to the top. Downvoting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing."](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down)